# Ios design strategy for iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, user-experience, ui-design

I'm looking for a design guideline for large data entry in iPad application. 
My application consist of more than 30 text field in one page that users have to input data in every each of them. My plan is to find the best way to have a user friendly app and easy to do the process as far as having a good design in the application.
Any suggestion?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about UI design/User Experience

Comment: Thanks For the advise, I will edit the the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how kosher this is to pimp my own stuff here (not like I make any $$ from it) but I've developed an open-source iOS project that handles quite nicely and easily just what you're looking for - user-friendly form/data entry.

https://github.com/mamaral/MAFormViewController

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I looked at you app and it looks great, and I liked the idea of how the next uitext comes up after pressing next, but I think I need something much bigger in terms of data entry as I said I have more than 30 text-field in only one page and I have about 5 different that have the same amount of data-entry.

Comment: by the way, you have a great program maintainability.

Comment: Thanks, and what do you mean by you need something "bigger"? You can have as many fields as you want in a form.

Comment: I have 12 rows that each of them has 6 column that 3 of those 6 columns stays the same and users only add info in the other 3, but in the page I also have other features, like a UIView that uses as a data entry tools and a picker view, In conclusion I need a more flexible environment that users be able to work with other tools at the same time. but the problem is that my design is more like a windows application or a web application structure and What I need is to make it more like ios interface if you know what I mean.